# Will PHP Meta hurt SEO?

Tags: php, seo, meta-tags

If I use PHP to place my meta tags such as keywords and descriptions will that hurt SEO? Will the bots not be able to crawl through the keywords and descriptions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP is performed on the serverside.  Therefore it takes place before bots see the page so it has no affect on the SEO.

Answer (score 2):

It won't matter since the information that the bots will pickup will be after the PHP code has printed out the statements into the HTML document. The keyword meta values themselves are kinda outdated so they won't be used much in regards to Searching Engine criteria.